# Geocoder failed due to ZERO_RESULTS

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geocoding

I am new to javascript and have been stuck at geocode,I am trying to get current location and get its placeid with geocode, if I have pass numbers to the lat lang it works fine else it gives alert geocoder failed due to ZERO_RESULTS,the code below is working just fine

```
var currentLatitude= 23.2147721;
var currentLongitude =72.6446714;
    function initialize() {
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;

        var latlng = {
            lat : currentLatitude,
            lng : currentLongitude

        };
        console.log("Geocoder" + latlng);
        geocoder.geocode({
            'location' : latlng
        }, function(results, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results[1]) {
                    console.log(results[1].place_id);
                } else {
                    window.alert('No results found');
                }
            } else {
                window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
                q
            }
        });
    };
```

code below is showing the error .

```
var currentLatitude,currentLongitude; 
 if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
        currentLatitude = parseFloat(position.coords.latitude);
        currentLongitude = parseFloat(position.coords.longitude);

            console.log("Latitude:"+currentLatitude+"Longitude:"+currentLongitude);

        });
    } else { 
        console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }

function initialize() {
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;

        var latlng = {
            lat : currentLatitude,
            lng :currentLongitude

        };
        console.log("Geocoder" + latlng);
        geocoder.geocode({
            'location' : latlng
        }, function(results, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results[1]) {
                    console.log(results[1].place_id);
                } else {
                    window.alert('No results found');
                }
            } else {
                window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);

            }
        });
    };
```

the src that i have used is

```
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOURKEYHERE&callback=initialize">
```

Comment: any help is appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, there is a mess in your code, though I'll try to help.

`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is an async function, u must wait for this function to end before you are creating another geocode request.

and who's responsible for calling the initialize function after the page has loaded? i am pretty sure that the part :

```
geocoder.geocode({
    'location' : latlng
}
```

should be inside the `getCurrentPosition` callback.

In addition take a look in the reverseGeocoding API :

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ReverseGeocoding